# Recommendations on how to tie a bunch of Get- to an output .txt

Tags: powershell

still learning my way around in PS and looking for some recommendations. I have been working on script to find if C is < or = 20GB and list the usual places like Documents and Downloads and measure their size. Now that it's all sorted, I want to put each folder it checks into a single output.txt but not sure how. Was thinking somehow tying all my Get-Childitems together but not sure where to start. Here is what I got so far.

```
#Check size of C and if its < or = 20GB

$FreeSpace = Get-PSDrive -Name 'c' | Select-Object Free

Write-Host "Free Space On C Left"

$TotalFreeSpace = $FreeSpace.free

$num = $TotalFreeSpace 
if ($num -lt 1TB) {
    $num = $num / 1GB
    $num = "{0:n2}" -f $num
    "$num GB"
}


$condition = $TotalFreeSpace
if ( $condition -le 20 )
{
    Write-Output "The C Drive's free space is > or = 20GB" 
}


#File Location Measures

$UserName = $env:UserName

Write-Host "Desktop Folder Size"

$Desktop = Get-Childitem C:\LOCAL\$UserName\Desktop | Measure-Object -Sum Length

$num = $Desktop.sum
if ($num -lt 1TB) {
    $num = $num / 1GB
    $num = "{0:n2}" -f $num
    "$num GB"
}


Write-Host "My Documents Folder Size"

$Documents = Get-Childitem C:\LOCAL\$UserName\'My Documents' | Measure-Object -Sum Length

$num = $Documents.sum
if ($num -lt 1TB) {
    $num = $num / 1GB
    $num = "{0:n2}" -f $num
    "$num GB"
}

Write-Host "Downloads Folder Size"

$Downloads = Get-Childitem C:\Users\$UserName\Downloads | Measure-Object -Sum Length

$num = $Downloads.sum
if ($num -lt 1TB) {
    $num = $num / 1GB
    $num = "{0:n2}" -f $num
    "$num GB"
}


Write-Host "Picture Folder Size"

$Pictures = Get-Childitem C:\LOCAL\$UserName\'My Documents'\'My Pictures' | Measure-Object -Sum Length

$num = $Pictures.sum
if ($num -lt 1TB) {
    $num = $num / 1GB
    $num = "{0:n2}" -f $num
    "$num GB"
}

Write-Host "Music Folder Size"

$Music = Get-Childitem C:\LOCAL\$UserName\'My Documents'\'My Music' | Measure-Object -Sum Length

$num = $Music.sum
if ($num -lt 1TB) {
    $num = $num / 1GB
    $num = "{0:n2}" -f $num
    "$num GB"
}

Write-Host "Videos Folder Size"

$Videos = Get-Childitem C:\LOCAL\$UserName\'My Documents'\'My Videos' | Measure-Object -Sum Length

$num = $Videos.sum
if ($num -lt 1TB) {
    $num = $num / 1GB
    $num = "{0:n2}" -f $num
    "$num GB"
}

Write-Host "Recycle Bin Size"


($RecycleBin = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'C:\$Recycle.Bin' -File -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum

$num = $RecycleBin.sum
if ($num -lt 1TB) {
    $num = $num / 1GB
    $num = "{0:n2}" -f $num
    "$num GB"
}

 |  Out-File -Path C:\LOCAL\$UserName\Desktop\$UserName'CDriveFullOutput'.txt

#Thanks to Lee_Dailey for Dev help!
```

Comment: please add an example of how you want the final output to look. i confess that i can't quite visualize it ... [*blush*]

Comment: So the way I know how to output to a .txt is see code below and since ill be doing Get-ChildItem Desktop, Documents, Downloads, Pictures, etc how can I grab all these Get-ChildItems to a singe output.                                                                                                                         $UserName = $env:UserName

$Desktop = Get-Childitem C:\LOCAL\$UserName\Desktop | Measure-Object -Sum Length  | Out-File -Path C:\LOCAL\$UserName\Desktop\$UserName'CDriveFullOutput'.txt -NoClobber -ErrorVariable ProcessError;

Comment: instead of sending them out to a file ... add them to a $Var and then send _that_ to your file.

Comment: Ah, ok cool. Makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: I have a additional question, how would you set up scripts to notify you? I was looking into Send-Mail Message but that seems no longer supported. I have been playing with getting each user to upload this file to SharePoint and it notify me when a file is uploaded.

Comment: the `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet is _deprecated_ ... but still works - and it has NOT been replaced quite yet. so use it until you find some reason NOT to use it. [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing I noticed is that you are counting the files sizes of files **directly** inside folders, but nothing that is stored in subfolders. You only use recursion on the Recycle Bin..

Secondly, you are repeating the code to format the size in every step, so I would suggest creating a small helper function for that to make the code much cleaner.

Then you hardcode the folder paths where I think there are better options for that and lastly, if your aim is to output 7 formatted numbers to a file, why not create a CSV file from the gathered info, so you have headers to tell you what each number stands for.

Try below:

```
function Format-ByteSize {
    # helper function to format a given size in bytes
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [ValidateRange(0, [double]::MaxValue)]
        [double]$SizeInBytes
    )

    $units = "Bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB"
    $index = 0

    while ($SizeInBytes -gt 1024 -and $index -le $units.length) {
        $SizeInBytes /= 1024
        $index++
    }
    if ($index) { '{0:N2} {1}' -f $SizeInBytes, $units[$index] }
    else { "$SizeInBytes Bytes" }
}


#Check size of C and if its < or = 20GB

$FreeSpace = (Get-PSDrive -Name 'C').Free
if ($FreeSpace -le (20 * 1GB)) {
    Write-Warning "The C Drive's free space is less or equal to 20GB" 
}

# get the sizes of the folders of interest. 
$desktopPath = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")
$DesktopSize = (Get-Childitem -Path $desktopPath -File -Recurse | Measure-Object -Sum Length).Sum
# seeing that the 'My Pictures', 'My Music' and 'My Videos' folders are INSIDE the 'My Documents' folder, you may
# want to think about adding the -Recurse switch to this path or not..
$DocumentSize = (Get-Childitem -Path ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments")) -File | Measure-Object -Sum Length).Sum
# If you've recursed the 'My Documents' folder, the below sizes will be included there
$PicturesSize = (Get-Childitem -Path ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyPictures")) -File -Recurse | Measure-Object -Sum Length).Sum
$MusicSize = (Get-Childitem -Path ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyMusic")) -File -Recurse | Measure-Object -Sum Length).Sum
$VideoSize = (Get-Childitem -Path ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyVideos")) -File -Recurse | Measure-Object -Sum Length).Sum

# the Downloads folder path is more tricky to find
$downloadsPath = (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:Downloads').Self.Path
$DownloadSize  = (Get-Childitem -Path $downloadsPath -File -Recurse | Measure-Object -Sum Length).Sum

# finally the recycle bin on the C drive
$RecycleBin = (Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'C:\$Recycle.Bin' -File -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
               Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum

# now put all this info in an **object** so you can save as CSV file with headers
$result = [PsCustomObject]@{
    FreeSpace   = Format-ByteSize $FreeSpace
    Desktop     = Format-ByteSize $DesktopSize
    MyDocuments = Format-ByteSize $DocumentSize
    MyPictures  = Format-ByteSize $PicturesSize
    MyVideos    = Format-ByteSize $MusicSize
    Downloads   = Format-ByteSize $DownloadSize
    RecycleBin  = Format-ByteSize $RecycleBin
}

# output to console screen
$result

#output to structured CSV file you can open in Excel
$result | Export-Csv -Path (Join-Path -Path $desktopPath -ChildPath 'CDriveFullOutput.csv') -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

On screen, this will output something like this:

```
FreeSpace   : 119,49 GB
Desktop     : 12,23 KB
MyDocuments : 26,99 MB
MyPictures  : 1,88 GB
MyVideos    : 119,90 GB
Downloads   : 573,88 MB
RecycleBin  : 537 Bytes
```

Comment: Wow, defiantly put my script to shame. This is much cleaner, and I hope to get my chops up to this someday. Thanks for showing me how you would do it. Once work is less busy ill go back and look into helpers as it is very redundant in my above code. I like that $results = [PsCustomObject]. Seems I didn't quite go deep enough w/ my variables. I will try this next scrip I work on. Thanks!

Comment: I have a additional question, how would you set up scripts to notify you? I was looking into Send-Mail Message but that seems no longer supported. I have been playing with getting each user to upload this file to SharePoint and have sharepoint notify me when a file is uploaded.

Comment: @XXLMandalorian `Send-Mailmessage` has indeed been declared obsolete (still works though). For securely sending emails, you could have a look at the [Send-MailKitMessage module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Send-MailKitMessage/3.1.0). A good site about how it works (and also alternatives) can be found [here](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-email/). As for the capabilities of Sharepoint in this, I really can't help you there I'm afraid..

Comment: @XXLMandalorian BTW. If you feel my answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking the **✓** icon on the left, as this will help others with a similar question finding it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again guys, really nice to finally wrap my head around arrays and how that helper works. Will have to re-write a bunch of older hardware measures lol

```
function Format-ByteSize {
    # helper function to format a given size in bytes
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [ValidateRange(0, [double]::MaxValue)]
        [double]$SizeInBytes
    )

    $units = "Bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB"
    $index = 0

    while ($SizeInBytes -gt 1024 -and $index -le $units.length) {
        $SizeInBytes /= 1024
        $index++
    }
    if ($index) { '{0:N2} {1}' -f $SizeInBytes, $units[$index] }
    else { "$SizeInBytes Bytes" }
}



$PCName = $env:computername
$UserName = $env:UserName

$FreeSpace = (Get-PSDrive -Name 'C').Free

if ($FreeSpace -le (20 * 1GB)) {

$Desktop = (Get-Childitem C:\LOCAL\$UserName\Desktop -File -Force -Recurse | Measure-Object -Sum Length).Sum

$Documents = (Get-ChildItem -Path C:\LOCAL\$UserName\'My Documents' -File -Force -Recurse | Measure-Object -Sum Length).Sum

$Downloads = (Get-Childitem C:\Users\$UserName\Downloads -File -Force -Recurse | Measure-Object -Sum Length).Sum

$Pictures = (Get-Childitem C:\LOCAL\$UserName\'My Documents'\'My Pictures' -File -Force -Recurse | Measure-Object -Sum Length).Sum

$Music = (Get-Childitem C:\LOCAL\$UserName\'My Documents'\'My Music' -File -Force -Recurse | Measure-Object -Sum Length).Sum

$Videos = (Get-Childitem C:\LOCAL\$UserName\'My Documents'\'My Videos' -File -Force -Recurse | Measure-Object -Sum Length).Sum

$RecycleBin = (Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'C:\$Recycle.Bin' -File -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Measure-Object -Sum Length).Sum


$Aray = [PsCustomObject]@{
    
    FreeSpace = Format-ByteSize $FreeSpace
    Desktop = Format-ByteSize $Desktop
    Documents = Format-ByteSize $Documents
    Downloads = Format-ByteSize $Downloads
    Pictures = Format-ByteSize $Pictures
    Music = Format-ByteSize $Music
    Videos = Format-ByteSize $Videos
    RecycleBin = Format-ByteSize $RecycleBin
}

$Aray | Export-Csv -Path (Join-Path -Path "\\HAWA-COL04\Support_Tools\Scripts\PS\Local Scripts\FullC\ScriptOutput" -ChildPath $PCName-$UserName'-FullCDrive'.csv)

}
```

Thanks to Lee_Dailey and Theo for Dev help!